# Анонимные (лямбда) функции в C++

Tags: c++, lambda, анонимная-функция

Я хочу сохранить анонимную функцию в структуре, которая будет вызываться время от времени:

```
typedef void (*tCallBack)();    // Объявление типа для вызова функции при нажатии
struct tControl {
    uint16_t x1, y1, x2, y2;    // Координаты контрола
    uint8_t autorepeat;         // Разрешение автоповтора
    tCallBack exec;             // Функция, вызываемая при нажатии
};
tControl controls[100];

controls[0].x1 = 200;
controls[0].y1 = 150;
controls[0].x2 = 250;
controls[0].y2 = 200;
controls[0].autorepeat = 0;
controls[0].exec = []()->void{Iref += 0.1;};
```

Написано согласно [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C++_(since_C++11)). Но что-то не работает. Компилятор ругается на последнюю строчку (где как раз анонимная функция):

```
Error: Expected an expression in "main.cpp", Line: 254, Col: 25
```

Пробовал также вариант:

```
controls[0].exec = [](){Iref += 0.1};
```

С тем же результатом.

При этом следующий вариант - работает:

```
void foo(void){
    Iref += 0.1;
}
controls[0].exec = &foo;
```

Есть нюанс с компилятором: это онлайн-компилятор [MBED](https://www.mbed.com/en/) - ARM-овский инструмент для написания ПО для встраиваемых платформ на базе ARM. Т.е. что там за C - черт его знает. Судя по всем форумам - 11 версия, так что должна такие конструкции поддерживать. Но я все-таки думаю, что проблема в моих кривых руках, а не в компиляторе.

Поправьте меня пожалуйста в части синтаксиса, если конечно там есть ошибки.

Спасибо!

Comment: Как минимум после 0.1 в `{Iref += 0.1};` нужна точка с запятой :) Надеюсь, что `Iref` - глобальная переменная? Словом, см. https://ideone.com/VSG3cc

Comment: @Harry, да, с точкой с запятой косяк, конечно :)))
Но что-то не помогло. Я вижу что по вашей ссылке работает, значит наверно все-таки компилятор недоСишный :(

Comment: Ваш компилятор, по-видимому, вообще не знает, что такое лямбда.

Comment: Причем тут компилятор? Указатель на функцию не может содержать адрес лямбда выражении

Comment: @ARHovsepyan может, если соблюден ряд условий https://rextester.com/PWCT5660

Comment: По сути, может если у лямбды между квадратными скобками ничего не написано.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, и если они обьявлены в одной и той же функции. Но тут указатель на функцию принадлежит классу, а лямбда в  main  определена.

Comment: @Croessmah, спасибо за поправку. Именно, если соблюден ряд условий...

Comment: *"если они обьявлены в одной и той же функции"* Хм, не слышал про такое ограничение. GCC на это не ругается: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4670f14ab7a8e2d6